# Correct code but Wrong ans :(

Tags: python

I am solving [Project Euler Problem #18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) in Python.

I have successfully solved the sample problem given there, but failed in solving the main problem. But the code is same.

Code is:

```
matrix = [('75', '0'),
    ('95', '64'),
    ('17', '47', '82'),
    ('18', '35', '87', '10'),
    ('20', '04', '82', '47', '65'),
    ('19', '01', '23', '75', '03', '34'),
    ('88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63', '67'),
    ('99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92'),
    ('41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33'),
    ('41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94', '29'),
    ('53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51', '14'),
    ('70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17', '57'),
    ('91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29', '48'),
    ('63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40', '31'),
    ('04', '62', '98', '27', '23', '09', '70', '98', '73', '93', '38', '53', '60', '04', '23')]

i = 0
j = 0
len = len(matrix )
sum = 0

for i in range(0,len):

    if matrix [i][j] > matrix [i][j + 1]:
        print matrix [i][j]
        sum = sum + int(matrix [i][j])
    else:
        print matrix [i][j+1]
        j = j + 1
        sum = sum + int(matrix [i][j])
print sum
```

Can anyone tell me where I am mistaken?

Comment: Please post the code in here, the question should be self-contained. Also: describe what answer you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: I guess your algorithm is plain wrong, and only worked by accident on the sample data.

Comment: I will start the compute process from the bottom.

Comment: I got 1064 as the total, and i expected this ans. but Its incorrect ?

Comment: `len` is a bad choice for an identifier as it is a Python built-in (that you have used).

Comment: [here's a correct solution that you could test your code against](http://ideone.com/8gmm47). It is obfuscated to avoid spoilers.

Comment: Oh! Solution! I was just seeking for the concept. though your solution is very Complicated.

anyway, thanx for the help. I will try to go through your post :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry but you're using an incorrect algorithm.
What you're using is called a [Greedy Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), but the correct algorithm to use is [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The major difference is that greedy choose a best current option as a choice, while dynamic programming enumerates EVERY possible option and generate a series of choices.

There is a simple case on which your solution(greedy) would fail:

```
0,  
1, 0,  
0, 0, 10
```

The best result is 10, but your algorithm would give 1 instead.

Think about it yourself for a moment, and then try seeking for information on Dynamic Programming. 
Project Euler is a great place and it's feels utterly great when you come up with a solution. So I won't say many on it for now. :)

**UPDATED:**

> But Ques: By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to "adjacent numbers" on the row below. I have made my code according to this Word. Sorry for interrupting but can you make me more clear with this word ?

Notice there would be actually `2^(n-1)` possible routes on a given `n` level triangle. And in the original problem `maximum total` means the maximum total among all these routes.
There's no grantee that your code would find the maximum among `ALL` routes since you only choose a better one in `TWO` choices at any step.

**AGAIN UPDATED:**

Actually in this problem since `n=15` is small enough, you can also enumerate all `2^(n-1)=16384` possible routes, summarize the total value of each route, and finally get a maximum total among all you get. However in [Problem 67 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=67) the problem size `n` is increased to 100 and it would be not possible to enumerate all `2^(n-1)=633825300114114700748351602688` routes.

By the way, I've posted a link to wiki page of Dynamic Programming, but I'm afraid it's to complex to read as a starter. Sorry for that.
 But don't worry, just Google [dynamic programming tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+programming+tutorial) and you'll got many useful resources to see :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I appreciate you ans.
But
Ques: By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to "adjacent numbers" on the row below.

I have made my code according to this Word. Sorry for interrupting but can you make me more clear with this word ? and its use!

Comment: @MohitAphale well I apologize for my poor English writing as a non-native speaker.. I'll try to edit the original answer to add some updates.

Comment: Ah! its fine!
thanks a  lot. I would be glad :D

Comment: @MohitAphale well it's a pleasure to help you :)

Comment: @ Pengyu CHEN
Ohhh okie! i got your point. I just Iterated the Max adjacent value, but yeah i can reach to a max total by the other value "too".

okie :) thanks for the help. have to iterate all possible adjacent values and then put the max total.
I will go through the links you provided.